# How to install wget on this?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, wget

I did download [RubyStack 2.0.3 for VMWare (Ubuntu 9.10)](http://bitnami.org/files/stacks/rubystack/2.0-3/bitnami-rubystack-2.0-3-ubuntu-9.10.zip) but I cannot download anything on it! It appears that all basic utilities are missing/screwed:

```
bitnami@linux:/var/tmp$ wget
-bash: wget: command not found

bitnami@linux:/var/tmp$ curl
curl: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared obj
ect file: No such file or directory

bitnami@linux:/var/tmp$ man wget
-bash: man: command not found

bitnami@linux:/var/tmp$ sudo apt-get install wget
[sudo] password for bitnami:
Reading package lists… Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information… Done
E: Couldn’t find package wget
```

Any ideas how can I download anything on this machine? (I don't have physical access to it)

**UPDATE**

You gotta be kidding me...

```
bitnami@linux:~$ ftp
-bash: ftp: command not found

bitnami@linux:~$ smbclient
-bash: smbclient: command not found
```

Comment: I've had fun with this sort of thing before. I've had firewall appliances that didn't come with GCC or even Make (smoothwall, anyone) so that doing **anything** out of the ordinary was more trouble than it was worth. Good luck!

Comment: How on earth somebody can survive without wget? <g>

Comment: BTW (and completely off-topic): Do you know pfSense? It rocks! ;)

Comment: Are your apt repos set up correctly? It's configured in /etc/apt/sources.list. More details are here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine

Comment: @Winluser, yes we decided to deploy on pfSense. I had those issues when we were evaluating all the options that were in the marketplace. We're very, very, very happy with pfSense (especially since v2.0 has fixed ALL of the issues we had with 1.2)

Comment: @Farseeker, a firewall shouldn't have GCC, make or any other build tools. That's what the dev version is for. ;)

Comment: @John, yeah true but Smoothwall charge a fortune for the full version of their firewall. I only wanted to set up a software RAID mirror. Anyway switched the PFSense, never looked back

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I use debian, not ubuntu, but, the method should be the same

First, try:

```
sudo bash
apt-get update
apt-get -f install
apt-get install wget
```

Barring that,

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Make note of the url prefix after deb

```
apt-cache show wget
```

look for:

```
Filename: pool/main/w/wget/wget_1.12-1.1_i386.deb
```

grab that in your local browser assembling the url portion from /etc/apt/sources.list and the filename portion from apt-cache show. scp the file to your machine,

```
dpkg -i wget_whatever.deb
```

If /etc/apt/sources.list is not set up correctly, try tekhammer's suggestion and then rerun apt-get update.

Comment: THANK YOU, man! I luv'ya! Your first 'apt-get -f' did the trick! Now I have wget! :)

Answer (score 0):

As cd34 mentioned, you need to use the package manager to install those utilities. It is a 'feature' as we try to make the appliances as lightweight as possible. We probably should document it better. Hope you enjoy Bitnami!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and I just had the same issue where sh and bash scripts where showing command wget not found. The solution for me turned out to be just put the full path to wget like so:

```
/usr/bin/wget "http://my-url-here"
```

instead of

```
wget "http://my-url-here"
```